# redis-rs request hmget to return incorrect results

Tags: rust

```
let hm: Vec<String> = redis::cmd("HMGET")
        .arg("channel_1")
        .arg("id1")
        .arg("id3")
        .arg("id2")
        .query_async(&mut con)
        .await
        .unwrap();
    // let guild_id_str   = hm.get("guild_id").unwrap();
    println!("hm {:?}", hm);
```

Returned result

```
hm ["1", "2"]
```

But this is the case in redis, missing nil in the return

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HMGET channel_1 id1 id3 id2
1) "1"
2) (nil)
3) "2"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I want to get a list of given fields and their values, and keep the same order as the request。
If it's a hashmap, it's better

Comment: `String` can not hold a nil (null) value in Rust. Have you tried using `Vec<Option<String>>` instead?

Comment: You are right, I didn't expect it at first, used ```FromRedisValue``` @justinas

Comment: Feel free to write a full answer for others that may run into the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I used `FromRedisValue`

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct HandleRedisValue {
    v: String,
}

impl FromRedisValue for HandleRedisValue {
    fn from_redis_value(v: &Value) -> RedisResult<HandleRedisValue> {
        let new_var: String = from_redis_value(v).unwrap_or("".to_string());
        Ok(HandleRedisValue { v: newv })
    }
}
```

```
let hm: Vec<HandleRedisValue> = redis::cmd("HMGET")
        .arg("channel_1")
        .arg("id1")
        .arg("id3")
        .arg("id2")
        .query_async(&mut con)
        .await
        .unwrap();
    println!("hm {:?}", hm);
```

This can also be handled

```
let hm: Vec<Option<String> = redis::cmd("HMGET")
        .arg("channel_1")
        .arg("id1")
        .arg("id3")
        .arg("id2")
        .query_async(&mut con)
        .await
        .unwrap();
    println!("hm {:?}", hm);
```